# Monitor says 'Out of Range' after booting up RPi

Tags: pi-4, display

I just bought a new Rasberry Pi 4 (this is the first time I use RPi) and connected it to an LG 24mp59g-p monitor, as well as to a keyboard and mouse and power source. I tried to set it up according to the official guide on https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up/4, but after booting up (the little raspberries appear just fine on the screen), rather than showing the desktop, my monitor starts to display 'Out of Range'. I1ve tried editing the config.txt with `hdmi_safe=1`, but seems to have no effect.
I would be happy if someone could guide me through this troubleshooting process.

Comment: What resolution is your monitor?

Comment: @CoderMike - that monitor is a full HD 1920x1080 monitor - apparently capable of 55-75Hz refresh rate

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm unable to comment here so I've put some notes in this answer

hdmi_safe is fully documented [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) and is normally a good fall back but it is possible that you have put it into an area not specifically for the Pi 4 hence the 'no effect' you are seeing.

First thing is to check your monitor is in the HDMI port closest to the power port

Second thing is to check where you have the line in and make sure it is in a section the Pi 4 actions - these sections are called 'conditional filters' and documented [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md)

Once you are happy this is set for the Pi 4 (a power off / on is better than a reset I've found) then you may need to set the actual monitor resolution using something along the lines of:

```
hdmi_group=x
hdmi_mode=x
```

The values to replace 'x' above can be found on [this web page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) and as an example, to set 1080p 50Hz for my monitor I would use:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=31
```

but my TV needs a different setting as its 30Hz

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=34
```

Comment: I didn't know about conditional filters, so thanks about that, although the hdmi_safe still hadn't worked, so I tried this instead of it: (The first 2 rows were pre-installed there, so I haven't tweaked them)

Comment: `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
#hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
overscan_left=16
overscan_right=16
overscan_top=16
overscan_bottom=16
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=1
config_hdmi_boost=4`

Comment: That's the same as hdmi_safe so I would not expect any difference - I would set the actual resolution.

Comment: With these settings the Raspberian desktop flashes up, but then everything black for a few secs, then it again flashes up for a quick moment and so on.. I can't do nothing about that, since I don't know the preffered settings of my monitor.

Comment: Google monitor docs or set low resolution and try any config / menu buttons for clue...

Comment: Okay, it turned out that it runs 1920x1080, 75 Hz, 16:9, but there is no so existing hdmi_mode for that.. What to do now?

Comment: it's capable of 55-75Hz (apparently) so ... CEA mode 16? (60Hz) ... and also DMT mode 82 is the same 1920x1080@60Hz

Comment: or `hdmi_cvt=1920 1080 75 6` and `hdmi_group=2` ... `hdmi_mode=87` ... `hdmi_drive=2`